# Elasticsearch returns broken HTML tags when I use Highlighting

Tags: html, elasticsearch, tags, highlight, querydsl

I have an HTML string in *content* like :

```
"content": "<h3><a href=\"http://blog.local/page/%D8%A2%D8%B2%D8%A7%D8%AF\">The Matrix has you </a></h3>follow the white rabbit."
```

I use `"fragment_size" : 150` to control the size of the highlighted fragment in characters  ,but it returns a substring with broken HTML tags :

```
           "highlight": {
                "content": [
                    "&#x2F;%D8%A2%D8%B2%D8%A7%D8%AF&quot;&gt;The <em>Matrix</em> has"
                ]
            }
```

How can I fix it in query DSL based on JSON?

```
{
    "query": {
        "filtered": { 
            "query": {
                "multi_match": {
                    "query": "matrix",
                    "fields": ["title","content"]
                    }
            },
            "filter": {
                "term": { "content_type": "page" }
            }
        }
    },
    "highlight" : {
            "order" : "score",
        "fields" : {
            "content" : {"fragment_size" : 150, "number_of_fragments" : 3}
        }
    }
}
```

And here is a sample response:

```
{
    "took": 8,
    "timed_out": false,
    "_shards": {
        "total": 1,
        "successful": 1,
        "failed": 0
    },
    "hits": {
        "total": 1,
        "max_score": 0.98773545,
        "hits": [
            {
                "_index": "myindex",
                "_type": "post",
                "_id": "101",
                "_score": 0.024953224,
                "_source": {
                    "ID": 101,
                    "content_type": "page",
                    "date": "1999-02-18 14:32:21",
                    "title": "Wake up, Neo",
                    "content": "<h3><a href=\"http://blog.local/page/%D8%A2%D8%B2%D8%A7%D8%AF\">The Matrix has you </a></h3>follow the white rabbit."
                },
                "highlight": {
                    "content": [
                        "&#x2F;%D8%A2%D8%B2%D8%A7%D8%AF&quot;&gt;the <em>matrix</em> has"
                    ]
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried it but I think you should specify the `encoder`in the highlight part to `html`.

```
{
    "query": {
        "filtered": { 
            "query": {
                "multi_match": {
                    "query": "matrix",
                    "fields": ["title","content"]
                    }
            },
            "filter": {
                "term": { "content_type": "page" }
            }
        }
    },
    "highlight" : {
        "order" : "score",
        "fields" : {
            "content" : {"fragment_size" : 150, "number_of_fragments" : 3}
        },
        "encoder": "html"
    }
}
```

See: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-highlighting.html

Comment: Setting encoder to HTML merely makes the HTML elements plain text, e.g. `<p>` would become `&lt;p&gt;`.